# Getting error like java.lang.String is not a valid external type for schema of double In below code

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop

My code Looks like below:

```
object DataTypeValidation extends Logging {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("SparkProjectforDataTypeValidation")
      .master("local")
      .getOrCreate();
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    try {

      breakable {
        val format = new SimpleDateFormat("d-M-y hh:mm:ss.SSSSS")
        println("*********Data Type Validation Started*************** " + format.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()))

        val data = Seq(Row(873131558, "ABC22"), Row(29000000, 99.00), Row(27000000, 2.34))
        val schema = StructType(Array(
            StructField("oldcl", IntegerType, nullable = true),
            StructField("newcl", DoubleType, nullable = true))
            )
        
        val ONE = 1
        var erroredRecordRow = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Row]()
        val newSchema = schema.fields.map({
          case StructField(name, _: IntegerType, nullorNotnull, _) => StructField(name, StringType, nullorNotnull)
          case StructField(name, _: DoubleType, nullorNotnull, _) => StructField(name, StringType, nullorNotnull)
          case fields => fields
        }).dropRight(ONE)
        val newStructType = StructType { newSchema }
        val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data), schema)
        df.show()
        print(df.schema)
 }

    } catch {
      case exception: Exception =>
        println("exception caught in Data Type Mismatch In Schema Validation: " + exception.toString())
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

```
exception caught in Data Type Mismatch In Schema Validation: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.String is not a valid external type for schema of double
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 0, oldcl), IntegerType) AS oldcl#0
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 1, newcl), DoubleType) AS newcl#1
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:292)
```

Comment: Hi, @smart_coder and Thanks for your reply. But here is the situation I can't change the Double type to String, which is defined by our client with proper documentation. Also in the schema, it should be double only.

Also,
the above code for map those columns into String type so that whatever value can be pass-through should get success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AnkitTomar,
this error is due to string value `ABC22` is mapped to `DoubleType`.

please update the following lines

```
val data = Seq(Row(873131558, "ABC22"), Row(29000000, 99.00), Row(27000000, 2.34))
        val schema = StructType(Array(
            StructField("oldcl", IntegerType, nullable = true),
            StructField("newcl", DoubleType, nullable = true))
            )
```

with

```
val data = Seq(Row(873131558, "ABC22"), Row(29000000, "99.00"), Row(27000000, "2.34"))

 val schema = StructType(Array(
            StructField("oldcl", IntegerType, nullable = true),
            StructField("newcl", StringType, nullable = true))
            )
```

so that you can retrieve the expected results,

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data), schema)

df.show()

/*
+---------+-----+
|    oldcl|newcl|
+---------+-----+
|873131558|ABC22|
| 29000000|99.00|
| 27000000| 2.34|
+---------+-----+
*/
```

**Note:** I could not find the usage of newSchema in your code, If you are following any other approach please comment

```
        val ONE = 1
        var erroredRecordRow = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Row]()
        val newSchema = schema.fields.map({
          case StructField(name, _: IntegerType, nullorNotnull, _) => StructField(name, StringType, nullorNotnull)
          case StructField(name, _: DoubleType, nullorNotnull, _) => StructField(name, StringType, nullorNotnull)
          case fields => fields
        }).dropRight(ONE)
        val newStructType = StructType { newSchema }
```

Comment: Hi, @Srinivas and Thanks for your reply. But here is the situation I can't change the Double type to String, which is defined by our client with proper documentation. Also in the schema, it should be double only.

Also,
the above code for map those columns into String type so that whatever value can be pass-through should get success.

Comment: `ABC22` is not a double value that's why spark got confused. So you have to handle this in the sequence itself, if not then will look for alternatives

Comment: That's actually my negative scenario, where the actual schema is a double type and I'm passing string value into it and it is giving error. But another reason is I can't paste actual project code here so that you can understand the issue. 
 case StructField(name, _: DoubleType, nullorNotnull,_) =>  StructField(name, StringType, nullorNotnull) in this line of code StructField is my columns and name are my column names which I'm converting from Double to String so that "ABC22" can pass. But it is not happening here.